# How to reshape the dataframe when the raw data is not good

Tags: python, pandas

I got a raw data from an api and the JSON file is like this:

```
{
  "lowestResellPrice": {
    "stockX": 313,
    "flightClub": 332,
    "goat": 332,
    "stadiumGoods": 380
  },
  "resellPrices": {
    "stockX": {
      "4": 313,
      "5": 382,
      "6": 404,
      "7": 425,
      "8": 366,
      "9": 373,
      "10": 325,
      "11": 330,
      "12": 374,
      "13": 374,
      "14": 335,
      "16": 350,
      "4.5": 375,
      "5.5": 390,
      "6.5": 409,
      "7.5": 398,
      "8.5": 344,
      "9.5": 355,
      "10.5": 340,
      "11.5": 400,
      "12.5": 407,
      "13.5": 405,
      "14.5": 427
    },
    "goat": {
      "4": 332,
      "5": 400,
      "6": 410,
      "7": 440,
      "8": 378,
      "9": 365,
      "10": 336,
      "11": 355,
      "12": 380,
      "13": 374,
      "14": 370,
      "16": 409,
      "17": 730,
      "4.5": 395,
      "5.5": 377,
      "6.5": 424,
      "7.5": 420,
      "8.5": 360,
      "9.5": 351,
      "10.5": 355,
      "11.5": 400,
      "12.5": 420,
      "13.5": 420,
      "14.5": 448
    },
    "stadiumGoods": {
      "4": 2915,
      "5": 4189,
      "6": 4084,
      "7": 4383,
      "8": 3664,
      "9": 3559,
      "10": 3484,
      "11": 3372,
      "12": 4039,
      "13": 5133,
      "16": 4039,
      "4.5": 4189,
      "5.5": 4563,
      "6.5": 4346,
      "7.5": 4308,
      "8.5": 4039,
      "9.5": 3589,
      "10.5": 3447,
      "11.5": 5133
    },
    "flightClub": {
      "4": 332,
      "5": 400,
      "6": 410,
      "7": 440,
      "8": 378,
      "9": 369,
      "10": 336,
      "11": 370,
      "12": 380,
      "13": 374,
      "14": 370,
      "16": 409,
      "17": 730,
      "4.5": 400,
      "5.5": 405,
      "6.5": 424,
      "7.5": 420,
      "8.5": 360,
      "9.5": 369,
      "10.5": 355,
      "11.5": 400,
      "12.5": 420,
      "13.5": 420,
      "14.5": 532
    }
},
  "imageLinks": [
    "https://image.goat.com/attachments/product_template_additional_pictures/images/033/925/077/medium/585885_01.jpg.jpeg?1583776607",
    "https://image.goat.com/attachments/product_template_additional_pictures/images/035/012/435/medium/585885_03.jpg.jpeg?1585958414",
    "https://image.goat.com/attachments/product_template_additional_pictures/images/035/012/439/medium/585885_06.jpg.jpeg?1585958413",
    "https://image.goat.com/attachments/product_template_additional_pictures/images/035/012/433/medium/585885_08.jpg.jpeg?1585958414",
    "https://image.goat.com/attachments/product_template_additional_pictures/images/035/012/436/medium/585885_04.jpg.jpeg?1585958413"
  ],
  "_id": "5f92732d82c05921d4602bab",
  "shoeName": "adidas Yeezy Boost 350 V2 Cinder",
  "brand": "adidas",
  "silhoutte": "adidas Yeezy Boost 350 V2",
  "styleID": "FY2903",
  "make": "adidas Yeezy Boost 350 V2",
  "colorway": "Cinder/Cinder/Cinder",
  "retailPrice": 220,
  "thumbnail": "https://stockx.imgix.net/adidas-Yeezy-Boost-350-V2-Cinder-Product.jpg?fit=fill&bg=FFFFFF&w=700&h=500&auto=format,compress&trim=color&q=90&dpr=2&updated_at=1594236988",
  "releaseDate": "2020-03-21",
  "description": "The Yeezy Boost 350 V2 'Cinder' features a neutral look on its signature construction. Built with Primeknit, the Cinder upper includes a tonal monofilament stripe on the lateral side. A heel pull-loop provides easy on and off, while a similar finish marks the cage around the Boost midsole. A gum rubber outsole provides traction.",
  "urlKey": "adidas-yeezy-boost-350-v2-cinder",
  "resellLinks": {
    "stockX": "https://stockx.com/adidas-yeezy-boost-350-v2-cinder",
    "flightClub": "https://www.flightclub.com/yeezy-boost-350-v2-cinder-fy2903",
    "goat": "https://www.goat.com/sneakers/yeezy-boost-350-v2-cinder-fy2903",
    "stadiumGoods": "https://www.stadiumgoods.com/adidas-yeezy-boost-350-v2-cinder-fy2903"
  }
}
```

I only want the "resellPrice" part, and do the reshape like this:

```
df = pd.json_normalize(data["resellPrices"])
```

the output is not what I want:

```
stockX.4  stockX.5  stockX.6  stockX.7  ...  flightClub.11.5  flightClub.12.5  flightClub.13.5  flightClub.14.5
0       313       382       404       425  ...              400              420              420              532

[1 rows x 90 columns]
```

I want the shape of the dataframe is:

columns: stockX, goat, stadiumGoods, flightClub

rows: 4,5,6,....

values: 332, 400, 410...

I find the reason is that the contents in the resellPrices is a `dict` not a `list`...As I cannot modify the raw JSON file(directly generated form an API), I wish someone can give me some advise.

Comment: Try `pd.DataFrame(data['resellPrices'])` ..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved!Just use the `DataFrame.from_dict` like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data["resellPrices"])
```

and the output comes:

```
stockX  goat  stadiumGoods  flightClub
4      313.0   332        2915.0         332
5      382.0   400        4189.0         400
6      404.0   410        4084.0         410
7      425.0   440        4383.0         440
8      366.0   378        3664.0         378
9      373.0   365        3559.0         369
10     325.0   336        3484.0         336
11     330.0   355        3372.0         370
12     374.0   380        4039.0         380
13     374.0   374        5133.0         374
14     335.0   370           NaN         370
16     350.0   409        4039.0         409
4.5    375.0   395        4189.0         400
5.5    390.0   377        4563.0         405
6.5    409.0   424        4346.0         424
7.5    398.0   420        4308.0         420
8.5    344.0   360        4039.0         360
9.5    355.0   351        3589.0         369
10.5   340.0   355        3447.0         355
11.5   400.0   400        5133.0         400
12.5   407.0   420           NaN         420
13.5   405.0   420           NaN         420
14.5   427.0   448           NaN         532
17       NaN   730           NaN         730
```

perfect!I LOVE PANDAS!